# Cnet Network Simulator

Tags: networking, package-management

How to install the Cnet Network simulator in Ubuntu 13.10. Why can't I install libelf package from `apt-get install`?

It says `unable to locate package`.

Comment: Welcome to Askubuntu.com! You probably already have libelf1 on your system. Try `apt-cache policy libelf1`. This will tell you what packages starting with libelf1 are already installed and/or available.

Answer (score 0):

To install Cnet : http://www.csse.uwa.edu.au/cnet/install.html

In above link it says to install libelf :
`sudo apt-get install libelf-dev`

I tried installing `libelf-dev` and it worked for me